# mongo log rotation does not work on windows

Tags: mongodb

When running

> db.runCommand('logRotate')

Response

```
{
"message" : "n/a",
"ok" : 0,
"$clusterTime" : {
    "clusterTime" : "Timestamp(1618333251, 1)",
    "signature" : {
        "hash" : "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=",
        "keyId" : 0
    }
},
"operationTime" : "Timestamp(1618333251, 1)",
"name" : "MongoError"
```

}

Even tried the suggested methods in this ticket https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7312
And when running logrotate, it  creates a log file named mongod.log.1 and it is locked by mongod process . mongod.log.1 only gets deleted when mongod is stopped/restarted.

**System Log in mongod.cfg**

```
    # where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  logRotate: reopen
  # configure this path appropirately and make sure the directory exists
  path:  C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\log\mongod.log
```

Not sure how to rotate mongo logs on windows properly?

Using mongo version 4.4.0

Comment: How did you define your [systemlog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#systemlog-options)?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  have added system log definition in mongod.cfg, thanks

Comment: Note clear what you actually expect. Did you try `logRotate: rename`?

Comment: Yes I tried that, and it does not work. My expectation is that logrotation works as it would in linux i.e create a backup of mongod.log as mongod.log.1.gz and empty mongod.log once configured size is exceeded. And mongod should not hold mongod.log.1

Comment: Or just want to know if log rotation is even feasible in windows ?

Comment: At least there is no native "logrotate" in Windows. I assume you will have to compress/remove old log files manually.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [Wernfried-Domscheit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3027266/wernfried-domscheit), a lot of research, weeks of trial and error and frustration I figured out a working solution on windows.

---

###### Prerequisites

- You have a MongoDB-Service running with a configuration file `mongod.cfg`
- [LogRotateWin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/logrotatewin/files/) is installed. This is a third party package to rotate the logfiles, based on the unix implementation. It provides many customizable functionalities like compression, when rotating is applied, old file deletion and more. You can find a full option list here [LogRotateWin Configuration](https://sourceforge.net/p/logrotatewin/wiki/LogRotate/).
- Basic knowledge of Windows Taskscheduler.
- Very basic knowledge of bat files.

###### 1. Adjust the configuration file of the MongoDB-Service

1. Stop the service
2. Open the `mongod.cfg` and find the code lines where the `systemLog` is configured:

```
# where to write logging data. 
systemLog:
      destination: file
      logAppend: true
      path:  E:\MongoDB\Server\4.4\log\mongod.log
      logRotate: reopen
```

Be sure, that you overwrite the path to your `mongod.log`. Be also sure, that `logAppend: true` and `logRotate: reopen` are set.

3. Delete the current `mongod.log` file
4. Restart the service

###### 2. Configure the logrotate configuration

This is my configuration. You can customize that to your own needs. But dont use `copy`, `copytruncate` and `create` and **dont** remove the `postrotate` commands! (In the discussion thread of SourceForge I saw that `notifempty` is not working and `rotate 10` results into permission errors, see my edit below this post)

```
E:\MongoDB\Server\4.4\log\mongod.log {
  nocompress
  daily
  size 100m
  missingok
  rotate 50
  postrotate
    E:\logrotate\notify_mongodb_service.bat
  endscript
}
```

This configuration rotates the logs uncompressed every day or if the size exceeded 100 megabyte. Maximum of 50 logs are stored, older files will be deleted. The postrotate script will be executed when the rotation succeeded.

###### 3. Create the `notify_mongodb_service.bat` file

This file sends a command to the MongoDB-Service, that a new file will be used. If you enabled authorization you can add `-u username -p password` aswell.

```
E:\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\mongo.exe --eval "db.adminCommand({ logRotate: 1 })"
```

- Change the path to `mongo.exe` to the location on your system.
- Save the file and  be sure that the path in the `logrotate` configuration is the same! (the line between `postrotate` and `endscript`

**The command is stored in an extra file, because the LogRotateWin interprets the Brackets (`{}`) of the mongo command and throws an Exception.**

###### 4. Check that all is working

1. Open the folder of the logs. You should see a single file `mongod.log`.
2. Open a terminal and check that logrotation is working ( `-f` forces the logrotation even if no trigger was triggered):

```
logrotate logrotate.conf -f
```

A new log file should occur. (for me it is `mongod.log.1`)
The `mongod.log` should be empty.

3. Trigger something that will be logged. For example connect with monogdbCompass to your MongoDB.
4. Check `mongod.log`. The connection should be logged there.

###### 5. Create a Taskscheduler Job to run logrotation periodically

I wont talk about taskscheduler creation but here is an example of my configuration. You can import that file and modify it to your needs.

Also change the path of the `logrotate.exe` to your location of your system.

This job runs every hour to check if one or multiple triggers of logrotate triggered:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2021-12-02T17:57:55.9541897</Date>
    <Author>Grayknife</Author>
    <Description>Execute Logrotate Hourly</Description>
    <URI>\docker\LogRotate</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT1H</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <StartBoundary>2021-12-02T18:00:00</StartBoundary>
      <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT30M</ExecutionTimeLimit>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>1234</UserId>
      <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>E:\logrotate\logrotate.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>logrotate.conf</Arguments>
      <WorkingDirectory>E:\logrotate</WorkingDirectory>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

---

I hope i could help someone with that guide.

---

##### Edit 2022-05-01

I faced the issue that `logrotate` throws exception when there are more than 9 files:

```
E:\logrotate>E:\logrotate\logrotate.exe logrotate.conf -f
logrotate: Force option set to true
logrotate: Exception: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

logrotate: StackTrace:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
   at System.IO.File.InternalMove(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean checkHost)
   at logrotate.Program.AgeOutRotatedFiles(logrotateconf lrc, FileInfo fi, String rotate_path)
   at logrotate.Program.RotateFile(logrotateconf lrc, FileInfo fi)
   at logrotate.Program.Main(String[] args)

E:\logrotate>E:\logrotate\logrotate.exe logrotate.conf -f
logrotate: Force option set to true
logrotate: Exception: Access to the path 'E:\MongoDB\Server\4.4\log\mongod.log.10' is denied.
logrotate: StackTrace:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
   at logrotate.Program.DeleteRotateFile(String m_filepath, logrotateconf lrc)
   at logrotate.Program.AgeOutRotatedFiles(logrotateconf lrc, FileInfo fi, String rotate_path)
   at logrotate.Program.RotateFile(logrotateconf lrc, FileInfo fi)
   at logrotate.Program.Main(String[] args)
E:\logrotate>
```

Quickfix for now is to set a maximum of 9 files.